# With pyspark, for a group in a dataframe, how to create an average of averages in subgroups?

Tags: pyspark, window, average, rolling-computation

for what seems to be a simple task, I find myself struggling. I want to create an average of averages using a 15-min rolling window but for some reason I can't get there.

Example:

```
data = [
        ("2023-07-12 09:00:00", "Togo", "R1", "C1", 100),
        ("2023-07-12 09:05:00", "Togo", "R1", "C2", 1000),
        ("2023-07-12 09:06:00", "Togo", "R1", "C1", 90),
        ("2023-07-12 09:09:00", "Togo", "R1", "C1", 86)
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Datetime", "Country", "Region", "City", "Sale"])
```

And I want a new column "region_sale_average" which shows, for each new row, the average of the city sales average in the previous 15 minutes. So, not a simple `.avg("Sale").over(country_region_city_window)`,
as I want the sales from city C1 to be equally weighted as sales in city C2, even if there are many more sales in city C1.

The output column "region_sale_average" should have these values :
100, 550, 547.5, 546

Does anyone have a clue how to produce this?

I tried to create a new column "avg_city" that does the sales average per city over the past 15 min, and then do a `avg(last(avg_city).over(city_window)).over(region_window)`,
but that would not just take the last "avg_city", but all values in the previous 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rangeBetween` for the window. But the result is a bit differ, should check your result.

```
df.withColumn('Datetime', f.to_timestamp('Datetime')) \
  .withColumn('timestamp', f.col('Datetime').cast('long')) \
  .withColumn('avg', f.avg('Sale').over(Window.orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(-15*60, 0))) \
  .show(truncate=False)
+-------------------+-------+------+----+----+----------+-----+
|Datetime           |Country|Region|City|Sale|timestamp |avg  |
+-------------------+-------+------+----+----+----------+-----+
|2023-07-12 09:00:00|Togo   |R1    |C1  |100 |1689152400|100.0|
|2023-07-12 09:05:00|Togo   |R1    |C2  |1000|1689152700|550.0|
|2023-07-12 09:06:00|Togo   |R1    |C1  |90  |1689152760|545.0|
|2023-07-12 09:09:00|Togo   |R1    |C1  |86  |1689152940|392.0|
+-------------------+-------+------+----+----+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response @Lamanus. I found a solution eventually, using a pandas_udf :

```
@pandas_udf('double')
def avg_sale_per_city(City: pd.Series, Sale: pd.Series) -> float:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'City': City, 'Sale': Sale})
    return df.groupby('City')['Sale'].mean().mean()
```

And this is how it's called :

```
country_region_window = Window.partitionBy("country", "region").orderBy(col("datetime").cast("long"))\
        .rangeBetween(-60 * 15, 0)
df = df.withColumn('average_region', avg_sale_per_city(col('city'), col('sale')).over(country_region_window))
```

Then I get the expected numbers.